# Spark Scala - converting Dataframe with one record and one column into Double

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The scala code that i wrote gives me data type errors. The main method which is testpredict_02 takes Double.

```
val featuresMD = hiveContext.read.parquet("hdfs://machine01:9000/models/nb/metadata/features")

def testpredict_02(VData: Vector) = { MyModel.predict(VData) }

def outerpredict_02(argincome: String,argage: String,arggender: String) = { 
featuresMD.registerTempTable("features_md")

val income = hiveContext.sql("select distinct income_index from features_md where income = argincome")
val age     = hiveContext.sql("select distinct age_index from features_md where age = argage") 
val gender  = hiveContext.sql("select distinct gender_index from features_md where gender = arggender") 

testpredict_02(Vectors.dense(income.select("income_index"), age.select("age_index"), gender.select("gender_index")))
```

---

```
Error :
<console>:43: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 required: Double
              testpredict_02(Vectors.dense(income.select("income_index"), age.select("age_index")))
```

Please help..

Comment: `income.select("income_index")` returns a `Dataframe`, not a `Double`. So `Vectors.dense(...)` creates a Vector of 3 Dataframes - I'm pretty sure that's not what you intended, and not useful in any way. What type does `MyModel.predict` expect?

Comment: Thanks Tzach. MyModel.predict expects Vector of DOUBLE.

income.select("income_index")
res2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [income_index: double]

 age.select("age_index")
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [age_index: double]

while the column data type is Double, since age.select("age_index") and income.select("income_index") returns sql.DataFrame, i am having this problem. Is there any other way to get just the column values please.

Comment: But each Dataframe contains _many_ doubles - a Dataframe is a distributed _collection_ of records... which one do you want? First? Any? All? If "all" - what if the 3 Dataframes don't have the same number of records? How would you build vectors for these values? Looks like you need to redesign the whole thing - this does not seem to be a correct use of Spark...

Comment: Thanks again. I have made sure, in the code that each dataFrame will have only one DOUBLE value (only one column). Ultimately what i want is to build something like 

testpredict_02(Vectors.dense(1.0,2.0,2.0)) wherein the values come from the DataFrame.

Comment: "one DOUBLE value (only one column)" --> that's just wrong - one _column_ contains multiple _values_, just like a column in a database (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_(database))

Comment: I understand that. However in the code, much ahead of this line, i have made sure that we won't get anything more than one column and one row. Ultimately i just want the value of that dataFrame as i mentioned in my previous comment.

testpredict_02(Vectors.dense(1.0,2.0,2.0))

where 1.0 is age_index
2.0 is income_index
2.0 is gender_index

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure each of the 3 Dataframes contains exactly one column and one record, you can get the first column of the first record for each of them:

```
def getFirstCell(df: DataFrame): Double = df.first().getAs[Double](0)

val vector: Vector = Vectors.dense(
  getFirstCell(income.select("income_index")),
  getFirstCell(age.select("age_index")),
  getFirstCell(gender.select("gender_index"))
)

testpredict_02(vector)
```

Comment: I shall try this and let you know Tzach. Thank you once again.

Comment: Three actions to get a single vector? It is an overkill, don't you think :)

Comment: @Tzach, that tip worked. Thank You.
zero323, Tzach, i know the design is not right, will work on that. As of now i need to do a quick POC and test the whole idea. Thank you.